Connect Wall With A Fun Fact
Instructions:
•   Four mystery words are replaced with a double question mark and must be deduced by the solver. NOTE: words are not necessarily in alphabetical order after the mystery words are deduced.
•   Divide the sixteen words into four groups of four. Each group contains one mystery word.
•   Next, fill in the blanks to complete four sentences. Each question mark represents one of the words in the above grid. Words can appear more than once. All four sentences must be sorted in alphabetical order (for instance, if the first sentence starts with GOLF then no other sentence can start with ABSENT)


Hm. I think I've got good candidates for the mystery words (one group is especially nifty, in my opinion), but I have a hard time to figure out how to complete the sentences. I have a feeling that the sentences describe a well-known paradox that you either know or don't know, like the last stanza here. (On the other hand, I may just be a bit dense, of course.)

Time for a small hint maybe?

small hint: rot13(rirel zlfgrel jbeq rkprcg bhg vf pbeerpg).

[This is a partial answer. I've filled in the blanks, but I'm not confident about my proposal.]
Groups and mystery words:

 ABSENT, MISSING, REMOVED, MINUS mean "lacking".
 ACCOMPLISHED, CREEP, CRITICAL, IMPOSSIBLE can follow "mission".
 BIND, GOLF, HEMP, JACK use each letter from A to P exactly once.
 FOUR, HUNDRED, SIXTEEN, ONE are square numbers.

 OP has confirmed the last three in comments. Hexomino proposed MINUS, which I'm not so confident about as a synonym of the other words in the group, but it makes a useful combination with ONE.

 (Other possibilities I've been thinking about are GONE, AWAY, NOWHERE or WITHOUT.)

The blanks in the sentences:

 I propose:

      JACK is correct
      JACK is MINUS ONE
      JACK is not MINUS ONE
      JACK is therefore IMPOSSIBLE

 This could be a logical paradox, where "Jack" is a placeholder of some sort. (I have no evidence that that word is used as a general placeholder habitually, though.)

 (From the instructions we know that each blank is one of the sixteen words in the connect wall, that words may be used several times and that the sentences are in alphabetical order after the blanks have been filled in correctly.

 I think that only the four mystery words are used and that the first word in each sentence is the same. That's a gut feeling and not enforced by the rules of the puzzle. Most of the given words don't usefully fill the blanks, except the numbers perhaps.)


This looks very similar to my own thoughts :) rot13(V unqa'g gjvttrq gur 'bapr sebz N-C' pbaarpgvba; V jnf ybbxvat ng pbafbanag-ibjry-pbafbanag-pbafbanag jbeqf naq cynlvat jvgu ZNGU nf n gbcvpny bcgvba; V yvxr gur arngarff bs WNPX gubhtu... V jnf guvaxvat bs FHOGENPGRQ sbe gur 'zvffvat' pngrtbel ohg gvzr jvyy gryy jung gur orfg guvat vf gurer...)

Along the lines of what Stiv said, could the replacement for OUT be rot13(ZVAHF)

Rot13(V jnf guvaxvat gung gur zlfgrel jbeqf unir fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu gur neenatrzrag. Yvxr ebj pbyhza qrqhpgvba fbzrubj (fvapr BC jevgrf "qbhoyr dhrfgvba znexf" (cbffvoyl 11,22,33,44) Nyfb, fvapr gur svefg vafgehpgvba fgnegf ol fnlvat qrqhpr gur zlfgrel jbeqf naq gura vafgehpgf hf gb gb tebhc gurz va 4f. Nf vs gur qrqhpgvbaf bs gur zlfgrel jbeq jnfa'g eryngrq gb gur tebhcvatf bs 4f, V zrna. V pbhyq or jebat bsp ohg whfg fbzrguvat gung V gubhtug bs.)

Rot13(V'ir tbg n uhapu gung gur svefg jbeq va gur zvqqyr gjb fragraprf vf "BAR", naq guvf vfa'g whfg n cnenqbk? Fb fbzrguvat nybat gur yvarf bs "N vf pbeerpg; Bar vf O P; Bar vf abg P O;O vf gurersber N." jvgu fbzr jbeqcynl gurer va gur zvqqyr gjb fragraprf, yrnqvat gb n wbxr va gur ynfg bar.)
